# create database on localhost mac

Tags: sql, database, localhost

I want to create a database on the local web server on my Mac and I have enabled PHP and mySql but I don't know where or how to add the sql statements to create the database. Where should I run these statements?

Answer (score 0):

You can start the Terminal application (by typing Cmd+Space and typing `Term` followed by `Enter`). Then you type the command below into the Terminal:

```
mysql -u root -e "create database testdb";
```

Once you have created the database, you will probably need to grant privileges to your Apache/Web Server user so they can actually access tables, so have a read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP).